# How to prevent Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN" occurs when declaring empty chart

Tags: html, angular, ngx-charts

I want to declare an empty line chart or clear the line chart data by simply emptying the chart data array. With this line of code in typescript:

```
<!--HTML-->
<ngx-charts-line-chart ...
    [results]="multi">
</ngx-charts-line-chart>

//typescript
this.multi =[];
```

However `Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".` occurred before I push data(or let say renew the data array with actual data inside) into the declared empty array or after I empty the data inside the data array.

Is there any way to make this error disappear? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes I have resolved this by myself, below is my answer thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I have find a work around in typescript.
Declare the object like this works in my case.

```
multi:any[]=[];
```